# Multiple (fuzzy) joins in a single query?

Tags: powerquery

I am experimenting with the Fuzzy Join capability in PQ (Excel for O365 64 bit)

A single join using Table.FuzzyNestedJoin() works as expected. However the behaviour of the "tweakable" parameters on the fuzzy join such as the match quality and transformation table aren't always easy to predict.

What I would like to do is perform the same join multiple times with varying parameters, and see the results side by side. Given source data like-

```
Table A                           Table B
=======                           =======
First     Last                    First     Last
-----     ----                    -----     ----
Jane      Johnson                 Jane      Johnson 
John      Johnson                 Joan      Johansen
Jim       Johnson                 James     johnson
Jimbo     Janssen                 Janey     Jamieson
...                               ...
```

I'd like to create a result table like-

```
                      (80% match)        (90% match)
First     Last        First80 Last80    First90 Last90
-----     ----        ------- -------   ------- ------
Jane      Johnson     Jane    Johnson   Jane    Johnson
John      Johnson     Jane    Johnson 
Jim       Johnson     James   Johnson   James   Johnson
Jimbo     Janssen     Jim     Johnson
...                   ...               ...
```

However if you just add multiple fuzzy merge steps to a query using the UI, each Fuzzy join result replaces the last, so there is only ever one new result column (containing the nested table of match results)

Although the documentation for Table.FuzzyNestedJoin says a new column is created for the result, just renaming the output column in subsequent Joins doesn't prevent each one from removing the previous one.

So- is there a way of achieving multiple Fuzzy Joins in a single query, or is the only option to produce a chain of tables along the lines of-

```
Join/Merge Tables A, B to produce Table AB
  Join AB to C to produce ABC
    Join ABC to D to produce final result ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out in the end, posting the answer in case it helps someone else. You can do this repeated fuzzy join if you use the advanced editor in Excel. The example below does a 3-level comparison in a simple hard-coded sequence-

```
// 3 Pass Fuzzy Match
let
    p80 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(
            ListA, {"Term"}, ListB, {"Term"}, "_80%", JoinKind.LeftOuter,
            [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true, Threshold=0.8]
            ),
        "_80%", {"Id", "Term"}, {"_80%.Id", "_80%.Term"}
        ),

    p60 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(
            p80, {"Term"}, ListB, {"Term"}, "_60%", JoinKind.LeftOuter,
            [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true, Threshold=0.6]
            ),
        "_60%", {"Id", "Term"}, {"_60%.Id", "_60%.Term"}
        ),

    p40 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(
            p60, {"Term"}, ListB, {"Term"}, "_40%", JoinKind.LeftOuter,
            [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true, Threshold=0.4]
            ),
        "_40%", {"Id", "Term"}, {"_40%.Id", "_40%.Term"}
        ),

    deDupe = Table.Distinct(p40),
    )
in
    deDupe
```